# error when trying to import tensorflow_probability (no module named keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

When I try to import tensorflow_probability I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
  File "PATH", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability import substrates
  File "PATH", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import all_util
  File "PATH", line 142, in <module>
    dir(globals()[pkg_name])  # Forces loading the package from its lazy loader.
  File "PATH", line 61, in __dir__
    module = self._load()
  File "PATH", line 44, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "PATH", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "PATH", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental import bijectors
  File "PATH", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.ldj_ratio import forward_log_det_jacobian_ratio
  File "PATH", line 46, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.glow import Glow
  File "PATH", line 45, in <module>
    tfkl = tfk.layers
  File "PATH", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "PATH", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "PATH", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I have the latest version of tensorflow (2.6.0) and tensorflow_probability (0.14.0), and I even installed keras separately (even though tensorflow includes keras too I think?) but I still get this error. I'm also using pycharm (with conda) if it matters at all.

Comment: Can you actually import keras? If not, that is obviously because it is not installed.

Comment: yes I can import keras

Answer (score 0):

`tensorflow-probability 0.15.0` worked with `Tensorflow 2.7.0`,  `Keras 2.7.0`, and `Numpy 1.19.5`:

```
import tensorflow-probability
```